# Django + FCGID on Fedora Core 9 -- what am I missing?

Tags: python, django, apache2, fastcgi, fcgid

Fedora Core 9 seems to have [FCGID](http://fastcgi.coremail.cn/) instead of [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/2) as a pre-built, YUM-managed module.  [*I'd rather not have to maintain a module outside of YUM; so no manual builds for me or my sysadmins.*]

I'm trying to launch Django through the runfastcgi interface (per the [FastCGI deployment](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/) docs).

What I'm seeing is the resulting page written to `error_log`.  It does not come back through Apache to my browser.  Further, there are a bunch of messages -- apparently from [flup](http://trac.saddi.com/flup) and WSGIServer -- that indicate that the WSGI environment isn't defined properly.

1. Is FastCGI available for FC9, and I just overlooked it?
2. Does FCGID and flup actually create the necessary WSGI environment for Django?  If so, can you share the `.fcgi` interface script you're using?  Mine is copied from `mysite.fcgi` in the Django docs.  The FCGID [Documentations](http://fastcgi.coremail.cn/doc.htm) page drops hints that PHP and Ruby are supported -- PHP directly, and Ruby through `dispatch.fcgi` -- and Python is not supported.

**Update**.  The error messages are...

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI! 
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
```

Should I abandon ship and switch to [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) and give up on this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try [modwsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)? It sounds as the preffered way these days for WSGI applications such as Django.

If you don't wan't to compile stuff for Fedora Core, that might be trickier.

Regarding to your first question, [this](http://fitri.manzanisimo.net/2008/05/23/hostmonster-python-25-subversion-14-django-svn-mysqldb-fcgid/) seems to solve the fcgid configuration problem.

Note that you don't want to run the django application manually like this: `python manage.py runfcgi`, the fcgi is run by apache automatically if the setup is correct and restarted by `touch your.fcgi`.

Comment: While the link is handy, I have the same problem that someone down in the comments has.  I suspect it's a version incompatibility.